# Rspec: How pass array to shared_example previously defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this shared_example code:

```
....

shared_examples_for 'crud_operation redirect to access denied page' do |actions|
    context "as an not authorized user" do
      actions.each do |a|
          specify "User should not be able to access ##a[:action] via #a[:method]" do
            send(a[:method], a[:action], a[:params])
            response.body.should have_content('Acceso denegado')
          end
      end
    end
end
```

And this spec's code:

```
...

let(:valid_crud_operation) do
  [
      {:method => :get, :action => :index, params: {}},
      {:method => :delete, :action => :destroy, params: {id: user.to_param}},
      {:method => :get, :action => :show, params: {id: user.to_param}},
      {:method => :get, :action => :edit, params: {id: user.to_param}},
      {:method => :get, :action => :new, params: {}},
      {:method => :post, :action => :create, params: valid_attributes},
      {:method => :put, :action => :update, params: {user: user.to_param, id: user.to_param}}
  ]
end

it_behaves_like 'crud_operation redirect to access denied page', valid_crud_operation
```

But, when i run test the result say that: undefined local variable or method `valid_crud_operation'

Anyone know how to pass an previously initialized array to a shared_example?

Answer (score 0):

To use a shared example, you must include it, as [shown in the documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples). Did you put this somewhere in your spec?

```
include_examples 'crud_operation redirect to access denied page'
```

Comment: after or before of my let sentences?

Comment: It doesn’t matter where, just before you use anything defined in the shared context. But I’d put it before the `let`s.

Comment: sorry but your suggestion not work... I'm not clear, i have shared_example not a shared_context.

Comment: Oops, I changed the answer. Are your shared examples in a separate file?

Comment: Okay, I added a link to the documentation in the answer, which shows how to work with shared examples.